# Switching between AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, switch-statement, boto3, profile, configure

I am using boto3 in VSCode for some automation in AWS. I have a default profile(which is my own) configured using "aws configure". Now I want to switch from my personal account to my company profile and have used the same command again to change the configuration. The problem is the configuration changed and is reflected in the config file but I cannot access my company profile as my personal account is still active even after the change. Is there a way to switch between accounts without this problem?
[image]

Comment: Can you post your boto3 code?

Comment: i cannot get results fro simple commands like "aws iam list-users". These commands are still returning users from my personal account instead of the newly configured company account. I still havent developed code in boto3. First i want my company's account to be configured.

Comment: Please follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) to set up and use your company profile.

Comment: `aws iam list-users --profile workprofile` `--profile` parameter is available in all `aws` commands, including `aws configure` to set it up initially. more details at the link that @jellycsc posted. One would assume that you searched AWS documentation before posting the question...

Comment: Hi, I have gone through that link before. The problem is when I changed the configuration using "AWS Configure" the new access id and the key got updated in the config file locally but the change is not reflected in the cli. When I am running a python code (boto3) all the results are related to my personal profile and I just need them from my company's profile. I have updated a picture for better clarification. Different commands are displaying different configurations. @Felix

Comment: if you do it correctly, the change *is* reflected in CLI. so figure out what you do incorrectly. Note, that I saw that `credentials` file *may* get written in correctly. Specifically, new profile title `[workprofile]` is written on the same line as the last line of you previous (default) profile. I had to manually enter carriage return and save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reasons you have values in environment variables - they override the values from profile (see *env* from Type column). This is what I get:

```
PS C:\> aws configure list
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
  profile                <not set>          None    None
access_key     ****************GOCJ shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************DMq1 shared-credentials-file
region                us-west-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config

PS C:\> aws configure list --profile govcloud
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
  profile                 govcloud          manual    --profile
access_key     ****************YXPK shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************J/77 shared-credentials-file
region            us-gov-west-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

note, `shared-credentials-file` where you have `env`

Comment: In my case "aws configure list" is returning the access_key and secret_key which does not exist at this time.They are deleted and I configured using new access_key and secret_key but still the change isnt reflected in cli. As you can see in the picture "aws configure" command has new access_key and secret_key and "aws configure list" is returning old access_key and secret_key.

Comment: Did you read my reply? access_key and secret_key **do** exist in environment variables! Please look carefully at your output. And then read through documentation once more...

Comment: Hi, Now I understood what you meant. Thanks for the solution. It worked FINALLY!